# Fetching JSON data using Sencha Touch

Tags: json, sencha-touch

How do I capture JSON data generated using PHP in Sencha Touch? Does anyone know a good tutorial on that?

I'm trying to get the JSON data using the codes below

```
Ext.util.JSONP.request({
    url: 'proc/getEvents.php',
    callbackKey: 'callback',
    callback: function(data) {
        var lists = data.results;
        timeline.update(lists); // Update events lists
    }
});
```

My JSON data is like (generated by getEvents.php):

```
{
   "sample":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "name":"131\/E Address",
         "desc":"This is where I live!!",
         "lat":"0",
         "lon":"0",
         "starttime":"0",
         "endtime":"0",
         "flag":"0"
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "name":"INOX",
         "desc":"Central Mall",
         "lat":"0",
         "lon":"0",
         "starttime":"0",
         "endtime":"0",
         "flag":"0"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now I want to display it in a template.

```
tpl: [
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div class="details">',
                '<h2>{name}</h2>',
                '<p>{desc}</p>',
            '</div>',
        '</tpl>'
     ]
```

Can anyone help me figure out where the problem is?? My javascript console says (with getEvents.php)

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html.
getEvents.php:1Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need your PHP server to respond in JSONP, not plain JSON. The 'P' meaning JSON-with-padding. The callbackKey you specified needs to be generated by PHP as follows:

```
callback({"sample":[
  {
     "id":"1",
     "name":"131\/E Address",
     "desc":"This is where I live!!",
     "lat":"0",
     "lon":"0",
     "starttime":"0",
     "endtime":"0",
     "flag":"0"
  }, { /*---etc---*/ });
```

Also, to make the MIME type problem go away, in PHP, put this code in before any echo or prints get done:

```
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // never, ever cache
    header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Answer (score 1):

While using json this works

```
echo utf8_encode(json_encode($json));
```

When moved to jsonp i did

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($results).')';
```